# How to make a VirtualPC boot again on VirtualBox?

Tags: boot, virtualbox, uuid

It was quite strange that after the Macbook crashed one time, VirtualBox won't start up the
 Windows XP, claiming the following:

[image]

Is there a way to boot it up again?  I renamed the `VBoxGuestAdditions.iso` to `000VBoxGuestAdditions.iso`
 but it is still the same message when restarting VirtualBox.

I then went to the Virtual Media Manager and removed the `VBoxGuestAdditions.iso` mounting 
 and then the error message changed to this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the UUID of the image. Whenever you change the name of, or copy a *.vdi file the UUID changes for that Virtual OS. You can accomplish this by using `VBoxManage` which is a Terminal utility.

Please refer to these instructions: [VirtualBox: How to change the UUID of Virtual Disk (vdi)](http://www.giannistsakiris.com/index.php/2009/05/06/virtualbox-how-to-change-the-uuid-of-virtual-disk-vdi/)